# Can i use a variable instead of a row number in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to create something similar to a PivotTable where if you type in a cell let's say F1 a value like "5", and another cell that uses that value as a variable let's say F2. F2=A(F1) for example and that should be equal to F2=A5. Is that possible or something similar.

The point of this is to easily fetch data from a row. So if all the data of 1 entity is stored in row 3 and columns A,B,C,D i can easily use that data where i need it by changing the value of a single cell

Example:
Column A is Name, B is Last Name, C is Address, D is City. You have 50 rows of data and another sheet for printing that data. Sheet 2 A1 is used to change a variable so that if i type "3" the cell A2 will show the data from Sheet1A3, A2 will show the data from Sheet1B3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In F2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,A2)
```

would achieve that.